# Have S3 get image from url in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

How can I have the S3 iOS SDK go to the url of an image and download it into the bucket? I'm trying to download a user's profile picture from Facebook.

Comment: Why can't you download the image yourself from the url and then upload to S3 either using the SDK or just by using `NSURLSessionUploadTask`?

Comment: Because I don't plan to do that for thousands of users. I need it to be programatic.

Comment: How do you expect S3 to do it without downloading each image separately? Do you want to give some kind of list of images to transfer from FB to S3 or what are you planning?

Comment: I want to pass a URL to S3 and say to the server "Download that to the bucket"

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  You have to download it (and by *you*, I mean *your code*, not you personally, and I'm reasonably sure that @Tapani meant the same thing) from its source URL and then upload it to S3.  Your code to download then upload to S3 could be in the app, or it could be on your app server, or it could be in Lambda, but it has to be somewhere.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so can you post an answer with some code I could use to save the image to a temporary directory on the device and upload it?

Comment: Do some googling and read the s3 sdk docs. You are not the first one to download a file from an url and uploading something to s3.

Comment: I was just thinking you might like the reputation @Tapani

Comment: Reputation is a small salary for writing code for you (or basically copy-pasting from web). Add a bounty of 100 and I might consider :-)

Comment: If it's so small then why does everybody else want it?